# How do I identify the max length from a Map's value set?

Tags: f#

**How do I identify the max length from a Map's value set?**

```
let numbers = [1;2;2;3;3;3;4;5;5]

let map = numbers |> Seq.groupBy id 
                  |> Map.ofSeq
```

**I want to do this:**

```
map.Values |> List.max
```

**or...**

```
let longestSequence = Map.map (fun (k, v) -> List.max(List.ofSeq(v)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get something similar to `Dictionary.Values` with `Map.toSeq >> Seq.map snd` so you can get the largest collected sequence in your `map` like this:

```
> map |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.maxBy Seq.length;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [3; 3; 3]
```

---

of course when your list is already in a sorted stage it seems strange to take the detour over `Map` as

```
> numbers |> Seq.groupBy id |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.maxBy Seq.length;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [3; 3; 3]
```

will do the same ;)

---

also if you think about the problem here can write a `List.fold` (with a additional map of the result) doing this as well which will only require to traverse the (sorted) list once ... maybe you can try to do this yourself ^^

Comment: @Scott Nimrod, Another way - Map.fold: (0, map) ||> Map.fold(fun acc _ y -> y |> Seq.length |> max acc)  https://dotnetfiddle.net/xc9dWX